# How to run scrapy with url parameters from php on linux debian

Tags: php, linux, scrapy, debian, debian-jessie

As the title says... how can i run my scrapy project with specific url paramter from php? I tried this on windows before and it worked perfectly, now on linux it's doing nothing.

On Windows working:

```
pclose(popen('cd .. & scrapy crawl mySpider -a "urls=http://www.example.com/'.$variable1.'/'.$variable2.'"','r'));
```

On Linux not working:

```
pclose(popen('sudo cd .. | sudo scrapy crawl mySpider -a "urls=http://www.example.com/'.$variable1.'/'.$variable2.'"','r'));
```

I checked already that the php file tries to execute the script as the user www-data so i added this user for testing purpose to sudoer list but it is still not working. When i try to use the command in the shell directly it is working though. I also checked if all files are owned by www-data and are executable and they are. My spider is owned by www-data and has 755 rights.
What am i missing here?

Edit:
When i change the user to www-data and try to run the command it works, just the php script is not running.

Comment: Instead of `scrapy` use complete path like `/usr/local/bin/scrapy` or whatever is the actual path on your system

Comment: i tried it, it works in terminal then but not through php script...
I just added the path to www-data environment so i can just use "scrapy" instead of full path. You have any clue why in terminal as user www-data it works but from php not?

Comment: Mostly it is because of difference between path variables. You can run `pclose(popen("env"))` to get the difference between the two environments

Comment: I checked it how you mentioned. It has same path as root. Output looks like this. APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2/apache2.pidPATH=/home/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/gamesAPACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2LANG=CAPACHE_RUN_USER=www-dataAPACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-dataAPACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2PWD=/var/www/html/example.com/public

Comment: Put everything in a bash script and then run that bash script through code. Also make sure to redirect error to stdout using `2>&1`

Comment: I will try and report.. if it works you should write this as an answer to my question.

Comment: I doubt it would work, but would show you the error that is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I figured out that php doesn't understand the Pipe operator.

The correct way to execute that command is the following:

```
pclose(popen('cd .. ; scrapy crawl mySpider -a "urls=https://example.com', 'r'));
```

The semicolon must be used instead.